# Windows program not responding issue with tkinter gui

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm having an issue with a program I created, Im trying to make a program that images a drive usind dism. When the dism command is run in cmd it gives a percentage of completion, so I am trying to take that percentage (using regex) and put it in my own progress bar gui however when I run my program, windows gives me a program is not responding error and I'm not sure why. The program continues to to run in the background and upon completion the error disappears, but the progress bar does not update. I have a feeling it is because I my run function has its own loop so maybe the tkinter gui isn't updating until that loop completes. If someone can confirm this or give me other reasoning that would be greatly appreciated. Also if you have any ideas for a solution to this I am all ears.

```
import shlex
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def run(command):
    progressBar['maximum'] = 100
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdin= subprocess.PIPE 
,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline().decode()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            matchObj = re.search(r'\d+\.\d%',output.strip())
            if matchObj:
                percentNum = re.search(r'\d+\.\d',matchObj.group())
                progressBar["value"] = 
round(float(percentNum.__getitem__(0)))
                print(type(progressBar["value"]))
                print(progressBar["value"])
            else:
                print(output.strip())
    rc = process.poll()
    progressBar["value"] = 0
    return rc





root = Tk()
root.title('Progress Bar')
root.geometry("300x100")

buttonFrame = LabelFrame(text="Options")
buttonFrame.grid(column=0,row=0)


backupCmd = 'Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:F:\my-windows-partition.wim 
/CaptureDir:"E:" /name:Windows \n'
button1 = Button(master=buttonFrame, text="Backup",command= lambda: 
run(backupCmd))
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

restoreCmd = ''
button2 =Button(master=buttonFrame, text="Restore",command= lambda: 
run(restoreCmd))
button2.grid(column = 50, row = 0)

button3 =Button(master=buttonFrame, text="Exit",command= lambda: exit())
button3.grid(column = 100, row = 0)

progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient="horizontal", 
length=286,mode="determinate")
progressBar.grid(column = 0, row = 3, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. For anyone struggling with this, you need to add a call to update the progress bar. For me I said, progressBar.update in my run methon

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue for a long time until I found an answer on stackoverflow about using multi-threading.

Tkinter window says (not responding) but code is running You to create a thread for sql queries function, like this

from threading import Thread

Thread(target = run, args =(command, )). Start()